# C++ reading sentences

Tags: c++

string a = MwZwXxZwDwJrBxHrHxMrGrJrGwHxMrFrZrZrDrKwZxLrZrFwZxErMrXxArZw;

Assume i have this data in my string . I want to record how many M , Z , X , D , J (including those capital letters i didn't mentions ) in in string how can do it ? My friends say use vector can do it but i does not really know how to use vector is there any alternative way to do it .

I tried using for loops to do and find the M , and reset the pointer to 0 to continue find the next capital value , but not sure is there any easier way to do it .

Comment: There are *many* ways to do it. Using a vector is not really required (as the `std::string` object itself is mostly compatible with `std::vector`). You have to be more specific about your problem. And please  take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: For *one* possible solution, read about [`std::isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset). All you need is one loop over the string to populate the set, and then one loop over the set to print the result.

Comment: You could also sort the string and then start counting until the character changes.

Comment: you can use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I'll show you a 'easier' way to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string str = "MwZwXxZwDwJrBxHrHxMrGrJrGwHxMrFrZrZrDrKwZxLrZrFwZxErMrXxArZw";
    map<char,int> map;

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str[i];

        if (isupper(ch)) {
            map[ch] ++;
        }
    }

    for (auto item : map) {
        cout<<item.first<<':'<<item.second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you'll only need to use 1 loop to solve your problem.

the 'isupper(int _c)' is a function from the standard library, it can tell you wether a character is a capital letter.

the 'map' is a data structure from the standard library too, it can do key-value storage for you.

this program outputs this:

```
A:1
B:1
D:2
E:1
F:2
G:2
H:3
J:2
K:1
L:1
M:4
X:2
Z:8
```

is this what you want?

Comment: YES ! this is what i want .if i want to do improvement such as  locations it found this . like Mw is time 1 Zw is time 2 Xx time 3 ZwDwJrBxHrHxMrGrJrGwHxMrFrZrZrDrKwZxLrZrFwZxErMrXxArZw what if i to want to capture all the times

Comment: and thanks you for you explanations especially the <map> i learnt a new thing thanks  . 谢谢

Comment: @TehWinSam  Great! Happy coding!

Comment: and if you want to check 2 or more characters, things will becomes very complicated. in that case, you will need to use 'regex'. try read the answer provided by @vikky

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
using namespace std;
// regex_search example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("MwZwXxZwDwJrBxHrHxMrGrJrGwHxMrFrZrZrDrKwZxLrZrFwZxErMrXxArZw;");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("[A-Z\s]+");
  map<string,int> map;

  std::cout << "Target sequence: " << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Regular expression: [A-Z\s]+" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;

  while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m)
    {
        //cout << x << " ";
        map[x.str()] ++;
    }
    //cout << std::endl;

    s = m.suffix().str();
  }
  for (auto item : map) {
          cout<<item.first<<':'<<item.second<<endl;
      }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct translation of "loop through the string and count the uppercase letters" into C++ I can think of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    string a = "MwZwXxZwDwJrBxHrHxMrGrJrGwHxMrFrZrZrDrKwZxLrZrFwZxErMrXxArZw";
    std::map<char, int> count;

    // Loop through the string...
    for (auto c: a)
    {
        // ... and count the uppercase letters.
        if (std::isupper(c))
        {
            count[c] += 1;
        }
    }

    // Show the result.
    for (auto it: count)
    {
        std::cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```